# Is there an Ubuntu Discord?

Tags: tag

So, I'm trying to upvote an answer here. Can't do that cause of lack of points.
I'm trying to leave a comment. Can't do that cause of lack of points.
But it seems I can leave a question.. so here it is.
Is there a Discord or live chat where I can go talk to people other than a forum?
Oh.. apparently I'm having problems even asking this question here cause of 'tags'

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList

Comment: Several thousands of users managed to pass those hurdles. Guess what... the alternative (ie. not having these hurdles) is far far far worse...

Comment: In Linux community people tend to use Matrix as replacement for discord. Use Element https://element.io/ (formerly riot, most feature rich client/web app) to sign-up and join distro specific channels. They are mostly active but not as much as IRC (if it feels too old for you). There's also nheko in repo, the next best client for matrix.

Answer (score 0):

This is a user support site designed around Questions & Answers.

There are other sites for Ubuntu support, including Ubuntu Forums, IRC and more, which can be found via https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/community-support/709

For *live* chat I'd also concur with @user535733's suggestion of IRC, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList

There is also Telegram groups, some of which are linked (via bot) to IRC, ie. you can speak to people to either on IRC from telegram, and vice-versa.

On IRC select your channel wisely, and stay within topic rules. Some site do require registration, others don't. If you want to talk outside of the topic, usually the best place is tan -*offtopic* room

This site does have chat too, however note it's a Stack Exchange server, so whilst I access AskUbuntu using my Ubuntu SSO (*Ubuntu One SSO*), I need to login to Stack Exchange to go to the Ask Ubuntu Chat as my Ubuntu SSO only gives me rights to askubuntu.com itself.  (this won't be an issue if you access the site via Stack Exchange login).

https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=askubuntu.com